# how to restrict and redirect from certain pages in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, restrict

I have a website that has an include folder which contains php templates and functions. If a user tries to access that folder. It may not harm website but I don't want my users to see those templates in an UN-organized manner. Instead, I want to restrict the user if he tries to directly access those files within include folder and redirect him to homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in an `.htaccess` file in that directory:

```
Deny from all
```

This is assuming you're using Apache or another web server that knows how to read and process .htaccess files.

For the redirect, instead of `Deny from all` you could try this instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/includes/$ http://www.yoursite.com/
```

Comment: what about redirecting to homepage ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the server such that this folder is not available to the public.  Alternately, structure the site so this folder is below the siteroot - this makes it completely invisible to the public.  Simply adjust your include paths and you're done.  I prefer this solution, because the files are completely off the radar unless you are logged in and have access to the file system.

Comment: Will those files(below site root) be accessible by php files inside site root ?

Comment: It's going to depend on your server setup, but I've never had a problem.  As long as your path in the include() or require() is right, it should work like a charm.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful.